# Neo4j - Is it possible to select a shortest path where nodes with a certain label have a particular value?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I have two graphs

1. a:Test -> b:Foo({type = 'car'}) -> c:Test -> d:Foo({type = 'car'}) -> e:Test
2. a:Test -> b:Foo({type = 'car'}) -> c:Test -> d:Foo({type = 'bike'}) -> e:Test

I want to write a shortest path query that will match the first path predicated on intermediate nodes of type Foo with type = car, but then fails to find the second a path in the second graph.

```
MATCH (a:Test {id: '1'} ),
  (e:Test {id: '5'}),
  p = shortestPath((a)-[:REL*]-(e))
WHERE all(r IN nodes(p) WHERE r.type = 'car')
RETURN p
```

But this obviously doesn't work, maybe with a subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how optimized this is, but it probably does the job. Basically we introduce a nested list comprehension syntax:

```
MATCH (a:Test {id: '1'} ),
  (e:Test {id: '5'}),
  p = shortestPath((a)-[:REL*]-(e))
WHERE all(r IN [x in nodes(p) where x:Foo] WHERE r.type = 'car')
RETURN p
```

Comment: Oh ya, seems like that worked, but it is reporting a cartesian product error - this seems like such an easy problem, but I suppose it's not!

Comment: You can help yourself with apoc expand procedures, will be more optimized

Comment: I have no idea what that is haha. Some of the stuff in neo4j is really cool, but some of the stuff like this is so tricky - you'd think you could just write some sort of visitor filter for path discovery